# Python - how to split the content of a cell if a "-" is given

Tags: python, dataframe, keyerror

I'm new to python and I have a maybe stupid question, but I'm stuck with it and would be thankful for any help.

I have a dataframe A. And in some entries in A there is a range given (for example: '1,0 - 2,0'). I want to take the Maximum in every entry (in our example: '2,0').

I tried it with two for-loops

```
nrow = A.shape[0]-1
ncol = A.shape[1]-1
for i in range(0,nrow):
  for j in range(0,ncol):
    if "-" in A[i,j]: 
       A[i,j]= A[i,j].split(' - ')[1]
```

But I get this error: KeyError: (0, 0).

Questions:
Is there a more elegant way to solve my problem?
What is the problem with my solution?

[edit: A.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOTzA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda functions

```
A['column']=A['column'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. That would actually really be a more elegant solution than mine. but i get an
IndexError: list index out of range
for every of my 'columns'. So I think the problem is maybe my dataframe?

Comment: it would be helpful if you gave the structure of your dataframe,type A.head() and add it to your question

Comment: added an image in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think that your split is actually working fine, but you are missing an entry in A for (0,0). In the error message it says that the issue is with the key (0,0).

If you would have in issue with the `[1]` in the split you would get a `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! i read about that.. but how can this happen. my dataframe is not empty and should have an entry in this position.

Comment: Very sorry for being annoying on the debug front, but can you run it without the split? Something like `print(A[i,j])` instead of the whole `if` section.

Comment: So there is no value at (0,0) ... if the data is loaded, maybe it's starting from (1,1) ... or the loader is not working. I would look into that part :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

- reshape `A` to `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- filter only values with `-` by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values, create `A2` by `expand=True` parameter, [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `,` to `.` if necessary, convert to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and get max value by [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html)
- last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to `A2`
- replace missing values in `A2` by values of `A` by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html).

---

```
np.random.seed(34)
L = ['1,0 - 2,0','3,0 - 2,0','4,0 - 6,0', 5.0, 'a', 'c']
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(L, size=(5,5)), columns=list('abcde'))
print (A)
           a          b          c          d          e
0  3,0 - 2,0  4,0 - 6,0  4,0 - 6,0  3,0 - 2,0          c
1          a        5.0          c        5.0  4,0 - 6,0
2          c  4,0 - 6,0          c  3,0 - 2,0  1,0 - 2,0
3          c          c          a          c  1,0 - 2,0
4          c          a        5.0        5.0          c

A1 = A.stack()
A2 = A1[A1.str.contains(' - ')]

A2 = A2.str.split(' - ', expand=True)
       .replace(',', '.', regex=True)
       .astype(float)
       .max(axis=1)
       .unstack()
print (A2)
     a    b    c    d    e
0  3.0  6.0  6.0  3.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  6.0
2  NaN  6.0  NaN  3.0  2.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0

A = A2.combine_first(A)
print (A)
   a    b    c    d  e
0  3    6    6    3  c
1  a  5.0    c  5.0  6
2  c    6    c    3  2
3  c    c    a    c  2
4  c    a  5.0  5.0  c
```

---

If always second value of range is `max`:

```
A1 = A.stack()
A2 = A1[A1.str.contains(' - ')]

A2 = A2.str.split(' - ').str[1].replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float).unstack()
print (A2)
     a    b    c    d    e
0  2.0  6.0  6.0  2.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  6.0
2  NaN  6.0  NaN  2.0  2.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0

A = A2.combine_first(A)
print (A)
   a    b    c    d  e
0  2    6    6    2  c
1  a  5.0    c  5.0  6
2  c    6    c    2  2
3  c    c    a    c  2
4  c    a  5.0  5.0  c
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no `(0,0)` key in `A`. Which is understandable. According to your image the top-left corner is empty. Just add a check for key exictence to your loop and you're good:

```
nrow = A.shape[0]-1
ncol = A.shape[1]-1
for i in range(0,nrow):
  for j in range(0,ncol):
    if (i,j) in A and "-" in A[i,j]: 
       A[i,j]= A[i,j].split(' - ')[1]
```